# I want to print all letters except the last one, then the last two, then the last 3

Tags: java

I'm trying to print a string like this:

```
cat
ca
c
```

But with my code now, I'm only getting

```
ttt
tt
t
```

code

```
public static String bingo(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        for(int i = 1; i <=s.length(); i++) {
            for(int k = 1; k <= s.length() - i+1; k++) {
                System.out.print(s.substring(len-5));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: Any word, like cat.

Comment: So for cat the output is cat, ca, c?

Comment: Yeah, but each time should be in the line below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it!

This is how it could be done with `while loop`.

```
public static String bingo(String s) {

    int index = s.length();
    while (index != 0)
        System.out.println(s.substring(0, index--));

    return s;
}
```

This is how it could be done with `for loop`

```
public static String bingo(String s) {
    for (int i = s.length(); i != 0; i--)
        System.out.println(s.substring(0, i));
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate from the length to 1 and print the sub-string in each line:

```
public static void bingo(String s) {
    for (int i = s.length(); i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(s.substring(0, i));
    }
}
```

**Output** (*for cat*)

```
cat
ca
c
```

Comment: This answer correctly fixed the return type that should be `void` since the `String` would either be empty at the end, or the original `String` itself.  OP should make sure to fix that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the other answers are correct, but why not also learn in a functional way?

```
// you can use the tails everywhere you need (require Java 9+)
static Stream<String> tails(String xs) {
    return Stream.iterate(xs, x -> !x.isEmpty(), x -> x.substring(0, x.length() - 1));
}

// usage example
public static void main(String[] args) {
    tails("cat").forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

The parameters are self-explanatory (see javadoc [iterate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-)) however:

```
.iterate(                                       // iterate
        xs,                                     // using `xs` as seed
        x -> !x.isEmpty(),                      // as long as the condition is true
        x -> x.substring(0, x.length() - 1)     // transform the current value
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String bingo(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    for(int i = 0; i <s.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(s.substring(0,len-i));
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### please find below mentioned solution

```
public String bingo(String s) {
    //if input is 'cat'(s=cat)
    int len = s.length();
    String data = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

        if (i == 0) {
            data = s.substring(0, len - i);
        } else {
            data = data + " " + s.substring(0, len - i);
        }

    }
    //getting output as 'cat ca c'
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what the code does, what the problem is and how does your solution solve the problem.

Comment: After taking an input ,on the basis of length of input  I have doing the substring operation ,and returning output by generating string as 'data' , so we get an output in single line only.(let me know if more clarification required)

Comment: If my input is "cat" then my output will be "cat ca c"